# Keep expanded UITableViewCell fixed on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have implemented SKSTableView and I used this command:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

when I press a cell that is expandable, and it goes on top. Now I'd like that when I scroll the expanded cell which went to top to stay fixed there until it's closed. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In UITableView you have the UIScrollView methods. So you can do something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    UITableViewCell *cell =[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    CGRect cellFrame = [cell convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];

    if (self.isStickToTop) {
        self.cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.cellFrame.width, cellFrame.size.height);
    }

    else {
        self.cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.cellFrame.width, cellFrame.size.height);
    }        
}
```

The `isStickToTop` is **your** maintenance `BOOL`variable that will indicate if the cell stick to top or not. Don't say u don't know ;)

Comment: I don't know why, but this method is not triggered :(
I don't say that I don't know, but it would be great if you expand your help too :D thank you very much :D

Comment: You should add this code lines in the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: the problem is that when I add:
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
my cell won't expand because I have set this already:
    self.tableView.SKSTableViewDelegate = self;
what do you suggest?

Comment: man I finally managed to fix this delegate issues, and edited a little bit this code like this:
     if (self->isStickToTop) {
             cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellFrame.size.width,      cellFrame.size.height);
         }
    
         else {
             cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y,      cellFrame.size.width, cellFrame.size.height);
         }
but it doesn't work, it makes a blank cell at the top, but it's still scrollable, it doesn't stay fixed there. :(